# Gtk-WARNING: Failed to set text from markup due to error parsing markup (BIT.TRIP RUNNER)

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, games, gtk

I am trying to run a game I downloaded from the Ubuntu Software Center called BIT.TRIP RUNNER. Upon running it, the game immediately crashes. When running from terminal, I get this output:

```
Fatal error
string: failed to copy string: dst too small (32 < 52)

(zenity:2515): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to set text from markup due to error parsing markup: Error on line 1 char 59: ' ' is not a valid character following a '<' character; it may not begin an element name
```

I should mention that I am running Lubuntu 12.04 64bit, I have tried removing and reinstalling via Ubuntu Software Center, and that I have the proprietary drivers for my GPU installed, although the error doesn't appear to be related to the graphics at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `/usr/local/games/bit.trip.runner` and exec `./bit.trip.runner`.
Works for me to solve the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a developer error.
the string : "dst too small (32 < 52)"
should be "dst too small(32 > 52)"
in order to be parsed as markup;

If you can't fix that string then you will probably have to contact the developer.